# Unit1.pas(72): 'END' expected but 'ELSE' found

Tags: delphi-7

```
begin
  D:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
if (Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '1' ) then
  begin
  Edit4.Text := '6,3' ;
  Edit5.Text := '11-12';
  Edit6.Text := '60';
  Edit7.Text := '100';
  end
else
  begin
  if(Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '2' ) then
  Edit4.Text := '3,2' ;
  Edit5.Text := '9-10';
  Edit6.Text := '25';
  Edit7.Text := '40'
  end
else
  begin
  if(Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '3' ) then
  Edit4.Text := '1,6' ;
  Edit5.Text := '8-9';
  Edit6.Text := '25';
  Edit7.Text := '40';
  end
end;
```

I have some trouble identifing the problem of `if else` Delphi 7 statement
[Error] Unit1.pas(73): ';' expected but 'BEGIN' found error.

Comment: Match your `begin` / `end` pairs and then observe that you have, `if .. then ... else ... else` The seond else is bogus. Clear indentation helps.

Comment: I dont need to use if again or what you say with if then else else?

Comment: i dont understand what mean if then else else

Comment: what do your refer

Comment: Look at the code. Look at the two `else` statements. They are both associated with the same `if`. That's an error. Can you see that?

Answer (score 2):

Your code has mismatched `begin..end` pairs. Fix the indentation and you will see this more clearly:

```pascal
begin
  D:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  if (Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '1' ) then
  begin
    Edit4.Text := '6,3' ;
    Edit5.Text := '11-12';
    Edit6.Text := '60';
    Edit7.Text := '100';
  end
  else
  begin
    if (Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '2' ) then
      Edit4.Text := '3,2';
    Edit5.Text := '9-10';
    Edit6.Text := '25';
    Edit7.Text := '40'
  end
  else
  begin
    if(Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '3' ) then
      Edit4.Text := '1,6' ;
    Edit5.Text := '8-9';
    Edit6.Text := '25';
    Edit7.Text := '40';
  end
```

You have an erroneous `if..else..else` sequence.

I'm guessing you meant to do something more like this instead:

```pascal
begin
  D := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  if (Edit1.Text <= '3') And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '1') then
  begin
    Edit4.Text := '6,3' ;
    Edit5.Text := '11-12';
    Edit6.Text := '60';
    Edit7.Text := '100';
  end
  else if (Edit1.Text <= '3') And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '2') then
  begin
    Edit4.Text := '3,2';
    Edit5.Text := '9-10';
    Edit6.Text := '25';
    Edit7.Text := '40'
  end
  else if (Edit1.Text <= '3' ) And (Edit2.Text >= '1') and (Edit3.Text = '3') then
  begin
    Edit4.Text := '1,6' ;
    Edit5.Text := '8-9';
    Edit6.Text := '25';
    Edit7.Text := '40';
  end
  ...
```

Which can be simplified a little to remove the redundant comparisons:

```pascal
begin
  D := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  if (Edit1.Text <= '3') And (Edit2.Text >= '1') then
  begin
    if (Edit3.Text = '1') then
    begin
      Edit4.Text := '6,3' ;
      Edit5.Text := '11-12';
      Edit6.Text := '60';
      Edit7.Text := '100';
    end
    else if (Edit3.Text = '2') then
    begin
      Edit4.Text := '3,2';
      Edit5.Text := '9-10';
      Edit6.Text := '25';
      Edit7.Text := '40'
    end
    else if (Edit3.Text = '3') then
    begin
      Edit4.Text := '1,6' ;
      Edit5.Text := '8-9';
      Edit6.Text := '25';
      Edit7.Text := '40';
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
```

Also, note that you can't use operators like `<=` and `>=` to compare strings as if they were numbers. You have to convert the string values to numeric values first. Which you seem to already be aware of by your use of `StrToFloat()`, but you are ignoring that value afterwards. Try something like this:

```pascal
begin
  D1 := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  D2 := StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  D3 := StrToFloat(Edit3.Text); 
  if (D1 <= 3) And (D2 >= 1) then
  begin
    if (D3 = 1) then
    begin
      Edit4.Text := '6,3' ;
      Edit5.Text := '11-12';
      Edit6.Text := '60';
      Edit7.Text := '100';
    end
    else if (D3 = 2) then
    begin
      Edit4.Text := '3,2';
      Edit5.Text := '9-10';
      Edit6.Text := '25';
      Edit7.Text := '40'
    end
    else if (D3 = 3) then
    begin
      Edit4.Text := '1,6' ;
      Edit5.Text := '8-9';
      Edit6.Text := '25';
      Edit7.Text := '40';
    end
    ...
  end
  ...
```